# Upload txt file on Google Drive Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm having some trouble uploading txt files on Google Drive. When I run the code, everything goes smooth, but when I go to Google Drive, nothing has been uploaded. Any thoughts?

```
json_key = json.load(open('jsonkey.json')
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/home/pi/Downloads/jsonkey.json',scope)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

media_body1 = MediaFileUpload('sensor1Text.txt', mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
body1 = {'title': 'Sensor1','description': 'A test document',
      'mimeType': 'text/plain'}

sensor1File = drive_service.files().insert(body=body1, media_body=media_body1).execute()
pprint.pprint(sensor1File)

media_body2 = MediaFileUpload('sensor2Text.txt', mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
body2 = {'title': 'Sensor2','description': 'A test document',
      'mimeType': 'text/plain'}

sensor2File = drive_service.files().insert(body=body2, media_body=media_body2).execute()
pprint.pprint(sensor2File)

media_bodyCV = MediaFileUpload('cumulativeViewText.txt', mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
bodyCV = {'title': 'CumulativeView','description': 'A test document',
      'mimeType': 'text/plain'}

CVFile = drive_service.files().insert(body=bodyCV, media_body=media_bodyCV).execute()
pprint.pprint(CVFile)
```

Comment: Use 'create' instead of 'insert'

Answer (score 0):

Use `create` instead of `insert` [for all].

Example:

```
CVFile = drive_service.files().create(body=bodyCV, media_body=media_bodyCV, fields='id').execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I try to use create this happens:

 `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'create'`

Comment: I changed to 'v3' and it debugged smoothly but still, there's nothing on my google drive.